# Dynamically change the Spring Data query strings

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-repositories

I have the following Spring Data Repository method:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM movies m " +
        "WHERE m.approved = true " +
        "AND NOT exists (SELECT user_id FROM movie_lists ml WHERE ml.movie_id = m.id and ml.user_id = :userId)",
        countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM movies m " +
                "WHERE m.approved = true " +
                "AND NOT exists (SELECT user_id FROM movie_lists ml WHERE ml.movie_id = m.id and ml.user_id = :userId)",
        nativeQuery = true)
Page<Movie> findAllApprovedNotListedInUser(@Param("userId") Long userId, Pageable pageable);
```

or another one

```
@Query(value = "SELECT m.* FROM movies m " +
            "WHERE m.approved = true " +
            "AND m.release_year >= :minReleaseYear AND m.release_year <= :maxReleaseYear " +
            "AND exists (SELECT movie_id FROM movies_genres mg WHERE mg.movie_id = m.id AND mg.genre_id IN :likedGenres LIMIT 1) " +
            "AND NOT exists (SELECT movie_id FROM movies_genres mg WHERE mg.movie_id = m.id AND mg.genre_id IN :dislikedGenres LIMIT 1) " +
            "AND NOT exists (SELECT user_id FROM movie_lists ml WHERE ml.movie_id = m.id and ml.user_id = :userId LIMIT 1)",
            countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM movies m " +
                    "WHERE m.approved = true " +
                    "AND m.release_year >= :minReleaseYear AND m.release_year <= :maxReleaseYear " +
                    "AND exists (SELECT movie_id FROM movies_genres mg WHERE mg.movie_id = m.id AND mg.genre_id IN :likedGenres LIMIT 1) " +
                    "AND NOT exists (SELECT movie_id FROM movies_genres mg WHERE mg.movie_id = m.id AND mg.genre_id IN :dislikedGenres LIMIT 1) " +
                    "AND NOT exists (SELECT user_id FROM movie_lists ml WHERE ml.movie_id = m.id and ml.user_id = :userId LIMIT 1)",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Movie> findAllApprovedNotListedInUser(@Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("minReleaseYear") int minReleaseYear, @Param("maxReleaseYear") int maxReleaseYear, @Param("likedGenres") Set<Long> likedGenres, @Param("dislikedGenres") Set<Long> dislikedGenres, Pageable pageable);
```

I'd like to dynamically in runtime to be able to set Query.value and Query.countQuery strings. Is it possible in some way? I'd like to be able to dynamically change the query strings.

I have 6 different parameters and based on presence or absence of values for them I'd like to change the `WHERE` part of the query.

Comment: The strings need to be static, but you can write your SQL to be dynamic based on a @Param value.  What is your requirement?

Comment: I have 6 different parameters and based on presence or absence of values for them I'd like to change the `WHERE` part of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this (I removed the countQuery to help keep it readable):

```
@Query(value = "SELECT m.* FROM movies m " +
        "WHERE m.approved = true " +
        "AND ( :minReleaseYear is null OR m.release_year BETWEEN :minReleaseYear AND :maxReleaseYear )" +
        "AND ( :likedGenres IS NULL OR exists (SELECT movie_id FROM movies_genres mg WHERE mg.movie_id = m.id AND mg.genre_id IN :likedGenres LIMIT 1) ) " +
        "AND ( :dislikedGenres IS NULL OR NOT exists (SELECT movie_id FROM movies_genres mg WHERE mg.movie_id = m.id AND mg.genre_id IN :dislikedGenres LIMIT 1) ) " +
        "AND NOT exists (SELECT user_id FROM movie_lists ml WHERE ml.movie_id = m.id and ml.user_id = :userId LIMIT 1)",
        nativeQuery = true)
Page<Movie> findAllApprovedNotListedInUser(@Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("minReleaseYear") int minReleaseYear, @Param("maxReleaseYear") int maxReleaseYear, @Param("likedGenres") Set<Long> likedGenres, @Param("dislikedGenres") Set<Long> dislikedGenres, Pageable pageable);
```